# Can we create unit test target for dependent projects

Tags: xcode, dependencies, unit-testing

I have an project which is dependent on the another project. But now i want to create an unit test target for the main project. Is it possible? because it will be referring the files of its dependent project.

Comment: It's not really a unit test at that point. A better term would be an integration test, and I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to do.

Comment: Suppose if we want to test the different methods in the class say an view controller and that view controller includes the files of the other project(which is a library) then how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to test your individual components in isolation, you need your components be loosely coupled, talking with each other only via interfaces, where possible. And you need a good architecture that regularly uses *Inversion Of Control*/*Dependency Injection* patterns everywhere. Then replacing single components with mocks or stubs or whatever is of course possible.

If you don't have such an architecture ('design for testability'), then you likely will run into problems when testing...

HTH.